# Akka Streams: How to group a list of files in a source by size?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

So I currently have an akka stream to read a list of files, and a sink to concatenate them, and that works just fine:

```
val files = List("a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt") // and so on;
val source = Source(files).flatMapConcat(f => FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(f)))

val sink = Sink.fold[ByteString, ByteString](ByteString(""))(_ ++ ByteString("\n" ++ _) // Concatenate

source.toMat(sink)(Keep.right).run().flatMap(concatByteStr => writeByteStrToFile(concatByteStr, "an-output-file.txt"))
```

While this is fine for a simple case, the files are rather large (on the order of GBs, and can't fit in the memory of the machine I'm running this application on. So I'd like to chunk it after the byte string has reached a certain size. An option is doing it with [Source.grouped(N)](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/snapshot/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#grouped(n:Int):FlowOps.this.Repr[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Out]]), but files vary greatly in size (from 1 KB to 2 GB), so there's no guarantee on normalizing the size of the file.

My question is if there's a way to chunk writing files by the size of the bytestring. The documentation of akka streams are quite overwhelming and I'm having trouble figuring out the library. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `FileIO` module from Akka Streams provides you with a streaming IO `Sink` to write to files, and utility methods to chunk a stream of `ByteString`. Your example would become something along the lines of

```
val files = List("a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt") // and so on;

val source = Source(files).flatMapConcat(f => FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(f)))
val chunking = Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 256, allowTruncation = true)
val sink: Sink[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("an-output-file.txt"))

source.via(chunking).runWith(sink)
```

Using `FileIO.toPath` sink avoids storing the whole folded `ByteString` into memory (hence allowing proper streaming).

More details on this Akka module can be found in the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html?language=scala).

Comment: So the issue with this is that the EOF doesn't have a new line, and in the output file, the end of file and beginning of the file fall on the same line. I originally had a solution like this, but I had difficulty splitting between files. Do you have any recommendations to this?

Comment: You could interleave your file sources with a "\n" before flatmapping them together. You should be able to achieve this by tweaking your source as follows:
`val source = Source(files).flatMapConcat(f => FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(f)).concat(Source.single(ByteString("\n"))))`

Answer (score 2):

I think @Stefano Bonetti already offered a great solution.  Just wanted to add that, one could also consider building custom GraphStage to address specific chunking need.  In essence, create a chunk emitting method like below for the In/Out handlers as described in this [Akka Stream link](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html#chunking-up-a-stream-of-bytestrings-into-limited-size-bytestrings):

```
private def emitChunk(): Unit = {
  if (buffer.isEmpty) {
    if (isClosed(in)) completeStage()
    else pull(in)
  } else {
    val (chunk, nextBuffer) = buffer.splitAt(chunkSize)
    buffer = nextBuffer
    push(out, chunk)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is closer to what I want, because not only am I concatenating, I also have to compress the file before writing it. I was thinking of using a combination of yours and Stefano's solution to make sure I can read lines adequately, and group chunks adequately.

Answer (score 1):

After a week of tinkering in the Akka Streams libraries, the solution I ended with was a combination of Stefano's answer along with a solution provided [here](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/file.html#example-size-based-rotation). I read the source of files line by line via the `Framing.delimiter` function, and then just simply use the LogRotatorSink provided by Alpakka. The meat of the determining log rotation is here:

```
val fileSizeRotationFunction = () => {
  val max = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MB, but whatever you really want; I had it at our HDFS block size
  var size: Long = max
  (element: ByteString) =>
    {
      if (size + element.size > max) {
        val path = Files.createTempFile("out-", ".log")
        size = element.size
        Some(path)
      } else {
        size += element.size
        None
      }
    }
}

val sizeRotatorSink: Sink[ByteString, Future[Done]] =
  LogRotatorSink(fileSizeRotationFunction)

val source = Source(files).flatMapConcat(f => FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(f)))
val chunking = Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 256, allowTruncation = true)

source.via(chunking).runWith(sizeRotatorSink)
```

And that's it. Hope this was helpful to others.